# List view will show most recent items from the bottom and old item will be invisible

Tags: android

I have a list view.
How can I show the item of the listView from the below.Item will be displayed from the bottom of the screen.when there are many items then it will show the most recent items from the bottom screen.when I scroll the listView to up then it will show the old item.

What is the efficient procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and then

```
listView.setSelection(items.size()-1);
```

after every addition to the data array.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own Adapter by extending baseAdapter and then in its getView method use the position variable to get the reverse order.

[here is an example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html)